# update_post_meta and update_field ony working when saving the post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, save-post, post-meta

I use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to store data in a custom field. I had latitude and longitude information stored separately, but I they need to be in one custom field so I made the function below. `$query` just queries all the relevant posts.

```
<?php 
$query = query_custom_posts(); if($query->have_posts()): 
while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
if(get_field('map_lat') && get_field('map_lng')):

$lat = get_field('map_lat');
$long = get_field('map_lng');
$coord = $lat.','.$long;
$post_id = get_the_ID();

update_post_meta($post_id, 'map_coor', $coord);


endif; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif;

?>
```

Now the function above works. The field map_coor gets populated with the lat and long separated by a comma (I can see the information in the field).

The weird thing is that if I use `get_field('map_coor')` on the front-end nothing shows up. If I save the corresponding post, then the info DOES show up.

In the function above I also tried to use the function `update_field` (from ACF) like this: `update_field($post_id, 'map_coor', $coord)` but the problem is still there.

So my question is; do I need to alter the function above or just run a function which saves all posts? If the latter is the case; how do I do that? I've found the hook `save_posts` but I'm not sure how to let it run through all the posts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the function [update_field from ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/) works a little bit different from [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). Can you see it?

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

If you use **update_post_meta** you should in my opinion use **get_post_meta** to get the meta. If you use **update_field** you should use **the_field** or **get_field** because ACF stores the key/values-pairs in a slightly different way.

Comment: *If you use update_field you must use the_field or get_field because ACF stores the key/values-pairs in a slightly different way* this is not entirely accurate. it's true that ACF stores values differently, but you can use `update_field` and retrieve the contents with `get_post_meta` just fine as long as you use `update_field` correctly. the important thing to note is that `$field_key` is not the same thing as `$meta_key`!

Comment: I changed that to "should in my opinion use". What you said is absolute correct but this "field-name/field-reference"-thing is very often the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Like I've described in my question, I've tried `update_field`. I've used it in combination with `get_field`. That gives the same outcome; the field value is saved, but when I query the custom field on the front-end it returns empty. I'll try `update_post_meta` and replace `get_field` with `get_post_meta`.

Comment: It does work when I use `update_post_meta` and `get_post_meta`. Still think it's strange that `update_field` and `get_field` don't give the same results. I'll mark the answer as accepted, thanks again.

Comment: I am using `update_post_meta()` and `get_field()` and it is working -- `update_field() was not working but I still don't know _why_.