# update_post_meta not adding anything.(Nor add_post_meta)

Tags: post-meta

So I have made some kind of importer(From another non WP db to my WP db) which handles everything in a click of a button.

Now it does correctly create a post type although one of the custom fields made with ACF in which I have to place the ID from the other DB is not filling in correctly and I did this according to `update_post_meta`. Now I have no idea what the issue is because when I look into my Wordpress DB it shows that it adds it correctly into the database but it does not add(Better said Show) WITH the custom post in the WP-Admin.

This is the code i've used:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Test" id="submit" name="submit">
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($result as $c) {
        $postargs = array(
            'post_title'   => $c->member_name,
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_type'    => 'bedrijf'
        );

        $thisid = wp_insert_post ( $postargs, true);

        if ( is_wp_error($thisid) ) {
            return get_error_codes();
        } else {  
            update_post_meta( $thisid, $meta_key, $c->memberID);
        }
      }
    }

    ?> 

</form>
```

A screenshot from my DB showing that it does add(Yes the meta key is correct as I only have one custom field). The meta value is also correct as I put it on LIMIT 1 in the query I have so it shows the first value of the DB only.

[image: DB Image]

EDIT: To be exact it adds it in the `wp_postmeta` table.

Comment: Ok, so the actual issue is that it's not showing it with the CPT (frontend or backend?) and not that it's not adding it to the database (the question-title seems to imply that)?

Comment: It is showing it in the database of Wordpress but it's showing as empty in the WP-admin for some reason.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of that in the wp-admin?

Comment: I solved it my friend but thanks for the help anyway. I was using the wrong property for ACF, only `update_field` is applicable. Wp-admin would just show 2 fields by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution in this post:

[update_post_meta and update_field ony working when saving the post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120895/update-post-meta-and-update-field-ony-working-when-saving-the-post)

The solution is to use `update_field` because `update_post_meta` uses a different method to update fields than ACF does. Do note that this is the correct order of using the code `update_field($meta_key, $meta_value, $post_ID);`.